# Cannot Install busybox on centos

Tags: centos, busybox

When running

```
sudo yum install busybox
```

On Centos 07 I receive this error

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.vorboss.net
 * extras: repo.uk.bigstepcloud.com
 * updates: repo.uk.bigstepcloud.com
No package busybox available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`busybox` isn't available for centos 7 , you can download the binary from [here](https://busybox.net/):

```
wget https://busybox.net/downloads/binaries/1.28.1-defconfig-multiarch/busybox-x86_64
mv busybox-x86_64 busybox
chmod +x busybox
./busybox
```

[How can I get started using Busybox?](https://busybox.net/FAQ.html#getting_started)

[access.redhat: Package Replacements](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/migration_planning_guide/sect-red_hat_enterprise_linux-migration_planning_guide-package_replacements)

```
 Removed package   Replacement/Alternative 
 busybox           normal utilities
```